# Statistics in medicine, any literature recommendations?

Tags: references, medicine

I work in the field of medicine as Ph.D. student. My primary work right now is modeling. And the more I get into it, and its statistics, I can see that I lack a lot, and what I have done, and others (not statisticians) are sometimes invalid, or at least it could be done better due to wrong assumptions, wrong tests, and so on.

As stated, I am really focused on this now, but the people I am usually around are not really "good" at statistics. They know the basics, as many do, but then not much more. I am not saying I want to become a statistician (since that in general would a new Master's), but I would like to be come a bit better than the average user of statistics. So could anyone recommend some great literature on stuff primarily used in the field of medicine? As of now I am going through Frank Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies", which I find pretty good so far. But I would also maybe like something a bit more digestive, if possible?

Comment: You might like http://www.intuitivebiostatistics.com.

Comment: The BMJ has nice tutorials/articles in statistics that are targeted at a researching physician audience. And on specific topics other journals like Statistics in Medicine may have accessible, but more in depth tutorials. In general, I suspect it depends a bit on what your main focus is, because many accessible applied books tend to be slightly application focused. Also, do you want to understand what others have done or do your own research? And yes, a lot that is published in medicine is nonsense - many journals don't even have stats reviewers (NEJM does & has at least fewer obvious blunders)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what particular things you're seeking to learn?

Comment: If you can master RMS you will be well ahead of the game. I would suggest not bothering to search for specific medical books but just pick the field you want and go for an advanced text in that area.

Comment: You would also like the blog http://www.fharrell.com/  by the author of RMS

Comment: Okay, so I probably need to specify at bit more. I am a physicist by education, and are now going into the field of medical physics. So I have had my fair share of math, but unfortunately it's been a while since I had my last big statistics course. So I do understand a fair amount of F. Harrell's book so far, but some things are still hard to understand fully. So that's kind of my "limit". So I don't need the dumbed down version of statistics. But I would like a larger overview, and then if I really need it, I could go more specific (like the modeling book of F.H.).

Comment: So basically some literature that gives a great overview of common mistakes, what to do, what not to do, etc., is maybe what I am looking for. And as stated, if I then, further on, need to get into more detail, I can obviously just search for that subject much more, if it were something on "how to do a t-test" (just an example).